# Firebase multi element removed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with firebase in my react-native app.

The problem assigne to remove element from database. I would remove few multiple items one after the other, but my app crashend when I did it.

Struct of my firebase database:

```
Workouts: id, data and trainings array.
Trainings: id, id_exe and sets array.
Sets: id, weight, reps.
```

When I had 1 workout day with 1 training exercises and 1 set, when I remove set, I want to remove set's trainings and that training's workout.

I tried:

```
Promise.resolve(database.ref(`/workouts`).child(`/${id_workout}`).remove()
.catch((error) => console.log(error)))
  .then(() => { Promise.resolve(database.ref(`/trainings`).child(`/${id_tren}`).remove()
    .catch((error) => console.log(error)))
      .then(() =>
      database.ref(`/sets`).child(`/${set.id}`).remove()); 
 })
```

Or

```
database.ref(`/workouts`).child(`/${id_workout}`).remove()
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)))
    .then(() => {
          database.ref(`/trainings`).child(`/${id_tren}`).remove()
            .catch((error) => console.log(error)))
            .then(() => {
                  database.ref(`/sets`).child(`/${set.id}`).remove()
                    .catch((error) => console.log(error)));
                  })
    })
```

That codes remove correctly nodes from database but app crashed with error. I think this is callback error but I don't know how resolved it.

This is communicate with error:
[image: Error after dispatch action]

When I remove sigle element everything is ok, but when I want remove element after remove another, app crashed.

Comment: The error suggests that the problem is with the expression in the `${set.id}` template literal. The `set` variable is likely `null`.

Comment: @cartant I check your suggestion but:
1. console.log logged right set.id (console.log in the deeper scope next to remove sets)
2. I commented parts of removed with ${set.id} but bug is still the same.
3. When I removed only set, workout or training bug don't exist, but when I chain it, removed after removed console alert error.
4. Thats part of code works good becouse it removed items from database but after remove app crashed. When I restart app the removed data dont exist.